# Rails deployment with mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deployment

I've a MySQL DB on a Rails app. I've a host&domain. I want to deploy my project. How should I it?

Comment: are you using any version control for your app?

Comment: Yes. I use git for version control.

Comment: Try this: http://ariejan.net/2007/06/20/rails-production-server-setup-and-deployment-on-ubuntudebian

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) or [Webistrano](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano). Capistrano brings deployment automation to Rails whether you're working with a single server or on a cluster of dozens. Webistrano is a nice Web UI for managing Capistrano deployments. Take a look at the [Capistrano Wiki](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/) for more detailed information.